# Stop redirect on an onsubmit function that adds another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, redirect

I am building an on submit function to create a div, id, and class, that builds a new tab. I'm able to see that on submit, it does seem to create the list item, the redirect causes the list item to be deleted and sent back to the original page. I wanted to add content to the tab, but that becomes useless once the redirect happens. If someone could show where the problem is occurring that would be helpful.

```js
/**Covers tab animations
May not matter just had to make sure*/
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e){
  var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  
  $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show();
   $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).animate({opacity:1, paddingLeft:'30%'}, 400);
   $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().css({opacity:0, paddingLeft:'0%'});
   $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).fadeIn(400).siblings().hide();
  
  jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
/** for the onsubmit functions*/
$(function(){
  //catches the information entered into form
 var $textInput = $('.examine input:text');
 
 $('#examine').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  
  //puts the information into a variable
  var newText = $textInput.val();
      //adds a new tab to list
  $('li:last').append('<li><a href="#tab5">' + "newText" + '</a></li>');
      
  
  $textInput.val('');
  
  
  
 });
});
```

```css
.tab-links{
 float:left;
}
.tab-links:after {
 display:block;
 clear:both;
 content:'';
}
.tab-links li {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid;
 letter-spacing: 0.09em;
 margin-left: -25%;
 
}
.tab-links li a {
 color: #f2f2f2;
 display: block;
 padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 
.tab-links a:hover {
 background:#a7cce5;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.tab-links li.active, .tab-links li.hover {
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.tab-links li.active a, .tab-links li a:hover {
 color: #666;
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
 
    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
.tab-content {
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
 color: #666;
 min-height: 150px;
 overflow: auto;
 
}
#tab1{
 padding-left: 30%;
}
#tab2, #tab3, #tab4 {
 display:none;
 opacity: 0;
 padding-left: 0%;
}

.tab-content p {
 margin: 20px;
 text-indent: -40%;
}

 
.tab-content.active{
 display: block;
 text-indent: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="explore">
    <form id="examine">
      <p>Search</p>
      <input type="search" name="explore" placeholder="Search Items" />
      <p>Choose Your Search Restrictions</p>
      <input type="radio" name="location" required= "required" value="Your School" />Inside
      <input type="radio" name="location" required= "required" value="Whole system" />Outside
      <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <p>Tab1 content</p>
      </div>

      <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <p>Tab2 content</p>
      </div>

      <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <p>Tab3 content</p>

      </div>

      <div id="tab4" class="tab">
        <p>Tab4 content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of `e.preventDefault;` you need `e.preventDefault();` with parenthesis .

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't believe I missed that. My fault, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `e.preventDefault()`, you forgot to call the second one.